# How can i add "pull to refresh" to tableView, not to UITableViewController?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uirefreshcontrol

i have viewController, and there are one tableView, where i want to add pull to refresh, but it havent got propertyrefreshConroller, what i need to do?

Answer (score 1):

For your kind of information Apple does't release refreshControl in its object library.
you can simply add this by using few simple lines:

```
UIRefreshControl *refresher=[[UIRefreshControl alloc] init]; 
[refresher addTarget:self
              action:@selector(refreshData)
    forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];

[tableView addSubview:refresher];
```

Where `refreshData` is your target method do whatever you want to do there.